# SQL Server compare two rows and combine cells from the second if first is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-transform

I've searched the forum, but either can't ask the question properly or don't understand the answers, and need someone to take me step by step through this.

The problem is:
There is a table in my database, Users. There are some duplicates, based on email comparison. Now, based on registration date, some of them have a higher priority (we would leave out the ones with earlier registration date), but some of the records with lower priority date have more info filled (such as gender, address, phone and so on).

The flow i want to get is: 
-> find duplicates based on email
-> prioritize the row with latest registration date
-> if a cell in this row is empty, fill it with data from the row with lower priority

p.s.
The problem is also, there may be up to three duplicated accounts with the same email.

I can't get my head wrapped around this..
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcxV.jpg)
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUFwC.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [userID] [nvarchar] PRIMARY KEY,
    [email] [nvarchar] (50),
    [priority] [nvarchar](2),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50),
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50)
)

GO

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1,'a@a.com','1','','');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2,'a@a.com','2','Dennis','Li');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (3,'b@b.com','1','Brent','Li');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (4,'c@c.com','1','','');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (5,'c@c.com','2','','Raji');
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (6,'c@c.com','3','Ben','Raji');
GO
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Which DBMS are you actually using? mysql <> sql server. And we are going to need some real details to be able to help you. Here is a great article explaining what you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!  Which one are you using???

Comment: Learn to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next CTE is only to display duplicated email's data. If you need a query that works for either duplicated emails and non-duplicated ones, you should remove the first CTE and done!

```
;WITH DuplicatedEmails AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Email
    FROM
        Person AS p
    GROUP BY
        P.Email
    HAVING
        COUNT(1) > 1
),
DuplicatedEmailUserData AS
(
  SELECT
      P.*,
      EmailRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Priority DESC) -- Assuming a higher priority comes first
  FROM
      Persons AS P
      INNER JOIN DuplicatedEmails AS E ON P.Email = E.Email
)
SELECT
    D1.UserID,
    D1.Email,
    D1.Priority,
    FirstName = COALESCE(D1.FirstName, D2.FirstName, D3.Firstname), -- Use COALESCE for the columns that might be NULL on 1st record
    LastName = COALESCE(D1.LastName, D2.LastName, D3.Lastname)
FROM
    DuplicatedEmailUserData AS D1
    LEFT JOIN DuplicatedEmailUserData AS D2 ON 
        D1.Email = D2.Email AND
        D1.EmailRanking + 1 = D2.EmailRanking
    LEFT JOIN DuplicatedEmailUserData AS D3 ON 
        D1.Email = D3.Email AND
        D2.EmailRanking + 1 = D3.EmailRanking
WHERE
    D1.EmailRanking = 1
```

Using this approach you might need to `LEFT JOIN` as many times as duplicated emails are.

Answer (score 0):

With the script below, we keep the registry with most recent `regDate`, and fill the NULL values with the previous registry for the same email.

However, if you have three or more users with same email, the older rows will be ignored, we just combine the most recent with the second most recent:

```
INSERT INTO Users ([email],[firstName],[lastName],[street],[city],[code],[country],[phone],[regDate])
VALUES ('a@a.com', 'Andrew', null, null, null, null, null, null, '2018-03-09 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO Users ([email],[firstName],[lastName],[street],[city],[code],[country],[phone],[regDate])
VALUES ('a@a.com', 'ANDREEW', 'Lopez', null, 'Santos', null, null, null, '2018-03-08 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO Users ([email],[firstName],[lastName],[street],[city],[code],[country],[phone],[regDate])
VALUES ('b@b.com', 'Bob', 'Wilk', null, null, null, null, null, '2018-03-10 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO Users ([email],[firstName],[lastName],[street],[city],[code],[country],[phone],[regDate])
VALUES ('b@b.com', 'Robert', null, 'Sandiego Street', 'Santos', null, null, '456 123 789', '2018-03-05 00:00:00');

SELECT * FROM Users;

INSERT INTO Users ([email],[firstName],[lastName],[street],[city],[code],[country],[phone],[regDate])
SELECT
u.[email],
ISNULL(u.firstName,old.firstName),
ISNULL(u.lastName,old.lastName),
ISNULL(u.street,old.street),
ISNULL(u.city,old.city),
ISNULL(u.code,old.code),
ISNULL(u.country,old.country),
ISNULL(u.phone,old.phone),
u.regDate
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Users old ON old.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Users oldMax WHERE oldMax.email = u.email AND oldMax.Id <> u.Id ORDER BY oldMax.regDate DESC)
WHERE u.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 new.Id From Users new WHERE new.email = u.email ORDER BY new.regDate DESC);

DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Users GROUP BY email);

SELECT * FROM Users;
```

---

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/997a0/5) you are a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
declare @T TABLE (
    [userID] int PRIMARY KEY,
    [email] [nvarchar] (50),
    [priority] tinyint,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50),
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50)
);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
       (1,'a@a.com', 1, null, null)
     , (2,'a@a.com', 2, 'Dennis','Li')
     , (3,'b@b.com', 1, 'Brent','Li')
     , (4,'c@c.com', 1, null,null)
     , (5,'c@c.com', 2, null,'Raji')
     , (6,'c@c.com', 3, 'Ben','Raji'); 
select t1.email 
    , (select top 1 tt.FirstName from @T tt where tt.FirstName is not null and tt.email = t1.email order by tt.priority asc) as FN
    , (select top 1 tt.LastName  from @T tt where tt.LastName  is not null and tt.email = t1.email order by tt.priority asc) as LN
from @T t1  
group by t1.email
order by t1.email;
```